# Is it possible to use the assets modal on the front end?

Tags: assets, entry

[Part 3 of a 3 part question:](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2033/how-do-you-delete-entries-from-a-frontend-form)

I am creating a proof of concept for a client in Craft where the client's customers can manage projects from the frontend of a Craft install.

A missing piece to the puzzle for full management is being able to give the user access to the assets modal and asset relationship field so they can better manage the files that are associated with the entry. Ideally they would be able to edit a field with existing content with the ability to associate new files or remove them all together (while still preserving the file in the upload directory, for this use case).

Is it possible to access the asset modal and manage the relationship field from the front end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Craft supports all of the fields within the Control Panel, but not on the front-end – the number of scenarios they would need to support on the front-end increases the scope of supporting a field dramatically.

Craft does however support submitting Assets from the front-end ([an example with Guest Entries](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1518/can-guests-upload-files-to-assets-in-an-entry-form/1993#1993)) and restricting Assets to user specific folders using [Dynamic Subfolder Paths](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/assets-fields#dynamic-subfolder-paths).

So you can do what you are describing, and may even be able to reuse some of the code they use to build out the functionality, but (currently) you will have to adapt it to your scenario and maintain it yourself.