# Front End Upload Form for guests

Tags: assets, form, entry

I've put together an entry form with a front end file upload, following the excellent answer [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2113/does-anyone-have-a-working-example-of-frontend-form-with-multiple-file-upload-d). It works perfectly, for logged in users only.

I'm wondering is this method is at all workable for guests?

When I attempt a file upload via the front end form when not logged in, I get:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost/login
```

The form submission works with text data, but the file field is not populated.

I'm looking to accept resume pdfs on a public job application form, hence the need for this to work for non-authenticated users.

Comment: Might be worth posting your form code. Make sure the <form> tag has enctype="multipart/form-data" as a parameter. Here's a related question: http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1518/can-guests-upload-files-to-assets-in-an-entry-form

Comment: Thanks - I did have that enctype in my form. I'm going to revise my question after doing a little more testing. I should have mentioned, I'm also using the Sprout Forms plugin for my form.

Comment: We do have Sprout Forms working in a similar use case to what you describe (guest users submitting resume PDFs). If you could update the question with a more comprehensive code example and any info on redirects or where the /login path seems to be coming from that might help.  Or drop us a note at sprout@barrelstrengthdesign.com with more info.